# How to control maximum concurrent users logged?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to control the maximum number of concurrent users logged (in session) in my rails app. But I don't know which is the best way.

I'm using rails 3.2.8 and devise 2.2.4.

Comment: This is just an idea but you could try to use https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store Then you have information about sessions in your database so you can try to have more control on them.

Comment: Do all users share the same login? Or do users have a separate logins? Devise also has a security extension with a session_limitable module to prevent the same user from logging in from multiple locations. I don't know if that's a step in the right direction? https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension

Comment: @ChrisLewis The users will have a separate logins, so this extension will not be usefull. Thank you anyway